# Will Linked Table in H2 cost a lot of resource?

Tags: h2

We are new to H2 database, and now we find that **Linked Table** in H2 might be a solution to our problem. The only concern here is we don't know how much resource that **Linked Table** will cost. Is the **Linked Table** just like a shortcut and the connection between databases created only when the CRUD operation happens? Or whenever there is a Linked Table, then there is a connection between two databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I checked the source code of H2 from [here](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/engine/DbSettings.java), I find that there is a field configurable called `shareLinkedConnections`, which could be used to specify whether the connections to the same database should be shared or not. And by default, it is set to `true`. The code snippet is as following.

```
/**
 * Database setting <code>SHARE_LINKED_CONNECTIONS</code>
 * (default: true).<br />
 * Linked connections should be shared, that means connections to the same
 * database should be used for all linked tables that connect to the same
 * database.
 */
public final boolean shareLinkedConnections = get(
        "SHARE_LINKED_CONNECTIONS", true);
```